# linebreak characters show as normal text in email

Tags: php, validation, email

I have an HTML form that sends a contact mail with PHP.

Everything goes well except for the body of the message that comes from a textarea, which will be filtered with both these functions:

1: mysql_real_escape_string()

OR

2:

```
function clean_data($input) {

            $input = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($input,",")));

            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())

                $input = stripslashes($input);

            $input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);

            return $input;

        }
```

when I put some line breaks, it converts to real visible \r\n

Instead of showing this:

Hello,

This is a test mail.

It shows this:

Hello,\r\n\r\nThis is a test mail.

If I pass the string as is without validation it works well.

Whats the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` should _never_ evaluate to `true`. Magic quotes are bad and I think you just found out why. http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found it!

after escaping I did this:

str_replace('\r\n', PHP_EOL, $message)

and it works now perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> Escapes special characters in the unescaped_string, taking into
>   account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe
>   to place it in a mysql_query(). If binary data is to be inserted, this
>   function must be used.
>
> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function
>   mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following
>   characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.
>
> This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data
>   safe before sending a query to MySQL.

The only processing you need upon insertion is mysql_real_escape_string, but it is preferred that you use prepared statements perhaps with PDO or MDB2.

That said, you can use mysql_real_escape_string for validating textareas. Here's an example function:

```
function validateContent($txtInput)
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$txtInput]))
    {
    $txtInput =  $_REQUEST[$txtInput];
    }
return mysql_real_escape_string(trim($txtInput));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this still gets the same problem "Hello,\r\n\r\nThis is a test mail."